# Is there any way to non-verbosely output all dependencies using to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails apps, I find myself placing a lot of nested `:include =>` statements in my JSON rendering code to include objects with relationships(direct and indirect) to the root object. Is there any way to get `to_json`(or a similar method) to automatically include all related objects without explicitly specifying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, override the #to_json method:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   def to_json(options={})
     super(options.merge(:include => :comments, :methods => [:arbitrary_field]))
   end
end
```

Comment: This won't include arbitrary fields though. I want every possible option to be included, not just `:comments`.

Comment: Check the latest version.  Specify :methods to add arbitrary fields.  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873